# How do I tell expect that I have finished the interactive mode?

Tags: expect

I am writing some expect commands in bash.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
set timeout -1  

expect -c "  

spawn telnet $IP $PORT1  
sleep 1  
send \"\r\"  
send \"\r\"  
expect Prompt1>  
interact timeout 20 {  
sleep 1  
}  

expect {  
Prompt2> {send \"dir\r\" }  
}    

"
```

My intentions with the script are, first let it telnet into a machine, when it sees Prompt1, let it give control to me, I will execute a command to load a specific image. Then wait until Prompt2 shows up (which indicates image has been loaded). Then Let it execute the further set of commands.

After running the script, I could get into the interactive mode, load my image. The problem is getting out  of interactive mode on the remote machine and giving back control to it.

The Error which I got:

```
expect: spawn id exp4 not open  
    while executing  
"expect -nobrace Prompt2 {send "dir\r" }"  
    invoked from within  
"expect {    
Prompt2 {send "dir\r" }  
}"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you planning to exit interact mode?  Is this by expecting `prompt2`?

Comment: The timeout value of 20, I assumed will get me out. Am I wrong here? Once I get out I want Expect to take control back and expect for Prompt2. Then it can execute the frther set of commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold...

1. You should interact with an explicit `return`, and give it some way to know you've released control... in this case, I use three plus signs and hit enter.
2. After you return control, the script will need to get the prompt again, which means the first thing you do after returning control to expect is send another `\r`.  I edited for what I think you're trying to do...

Example follows...

```
#!/bin/bash  
set timeout -1  

expect -c "  

spawn telnet $IP $PORT1  
sleep 1  
send \"\r\"  
send \"\r\"  
expect Prompt1>  
interact +++ return

send \"\r\"
expect {  
Prompt2> {send \"dir\r\" }  
}
"
```

Answer (score 1):

### return = fail

`return` didn't work for me because in my case, it was not a shell that can simply prompt me again with the same question. I couldn't figure out how to get it to match on what was printed before I did `return`.

### expect_out (to fix above solution) = fail

The manual says:

```
Upon matching a pattern (or eof or full_buffer), any matching and previously unmatched output is saved in the variable expect_out(buffer).
```

But I couldn't get that to work (except where I used it below, combined with `-indices` which makes it work there, and no idea how to make it work to get previous output fed into a new `expect { ... }` block.)

### expect_user

And the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33886098/1134343) using `expect_user` didn't work for me either because it had no explanation and wasn't used how I wanted, so didn't know how to apply this limited example in my actual expect file.

### my solution

So what I did instead was avoid the interactive mode, and just have a way to provide input, one line at a time. It even works for arrow keys and `alt+...`, (in dpkg Dialog questions) but not for simply `<enter>` sometimes (hit alt+y for `<Yes>` or alt+o for `<Ok>` for those in dpkg Dialog). (anyone know how to send an enter? not '\n', but the enter key like dpkg Dialog wants?)

The `-i $user_spawn_id` part means that instead of only looking at your spawned process, it also looks at what the user types. This affects everything after it, so you use `expect_after` or put it below the rest, not `expect_before`. `-indices` makes it possible to read the captured part of the regular expression that matches. `expect_out(1,string)` is the part I wanted (all except the colon).

```
expect_after {
    -i $user_spawn_id
    # single line custom input; prefix with : and the rest is sent to the application
    -indices -re ":(.*)" {
        send "$expect_out(1,string)"
    }
}
```

Using `expect_after` means it will apply to all following `expect` blocks until the next `expect_after`. So you can put that anywhere above your usual `expect` lines in the file.

### and my case/purpose

I wanted to automate do-release-upgrade which does not properly support the usual Debian non-interactive flags (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035893/60290))...it just hangs and ignores input instead of proceeding after a question. But the questions are unpredictable... and an aborted upgrade means you could mess up your system, so some fallback to interaction is required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike for that suggestion.
I tweaked it a bit and adapted it to my problem.

Changed code:

```
expect Prompt1>  
interact timeout 10 return  
expect {  
timeout {exp_continue}  
Prompt2 {send \"dir\r\" }  
}
```

The timeout 10 value is not related to the `set timeout -1` we set initally. Hence I can execute whatever commands I want on `Prompt1` and once keyboard is idle for 10 seconds then script gains control back.

Even after this I faced one more problem, After `Prompt1`, I wanted to execute command to load a particular image. The image loading takes around 2 minutes. Even with `set timeout -1` the script was timing out waiting for `Prompt2`. It's not the telnet timeout even, which i verified. But the solution for this is the adding exp_continue in case of timeout within the expect statement.

For your `set timeout -1` to take into effect it should be placed before the spawn telnet command within expect.